# AWS - EB CLI Set account level default environment when `eb init`ing a specific EB application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When running `eb init` for the first time, it has you first set up the region, then the application, and, if you select an existing application, select an environment. It lists your options, then said `(default is 1):` at the bottom, and waits for your input.

For this specific application, our production environment is the universal default. I'm afraid that we'll end up having someone accidentally deploy to production down the road if we don't swap that now.

Is there anyway to change the order these environments are listed / which is the universal default when first running `eb init` either on the AWS console or with the EB CLI? I haven't been able to find anything other than documentation mentioning setting the default through the flow I'm talking about here. I want to change the preset default, not set the configuration default for when you eb deploy and don't specify an environment.

Comment: Ever managed to solve this? Hunting for the same thing ...

Comment: Unfortunately not, have just been taking lots of care while deploying branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it in our deployment script with just some bash handiness. You can actually `printf` to the `eb init` command, just as you would type in the actual options.

In our script, it looks like this:

> printf '4\n\n\nY\n\n' | eb init ${application}-service >> logging.log

${application} is, evidently, a parameter passed to the script.

A `\n` is a newline, which is the same as pressing the return key. What this does, is the following:

- '4' for the first question
- Simple return for the second (= default)
- Simple return for the third (= default)
- 'Y' for the fourth question
- Simple return for the fifth (= default)

As you can see, I pipe the result to a `logging.log` file, simply to not show anything in the console.

For our setup (YMMV), I made sure that the user only can enter certain params (usually, the environment and the application name). Don't know if it works for you, it does for me.

For sake of completeness, I got the idea from the infamous `yes` script in Unix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)